# Passing reference variables to function

Tags: c++

Why are reference variable are considered as pointer in parameter passing?

```
int x; 
void fun(&x);
void fun(int* y)
{
    ------some code----
}
```

Here, reference of variable `x` is passed to `fun()` function. Local variable `y` in `fun()` contains reference of variable `x` but `y` is declared as pointer. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mistaken `&x` is not a 'reference variable'. It is a pointer to `x`, `&` is the *address-of* operator, which returns the address (i.e. a pointer) of whatever argument it's given.

It's confusing because `&` is used to mean a reference in *type declarations* but it's meaning in expressions is different.

For example

```
int x;
int& y = x; // here & means reference because 'int&' is a type declaration
int* z = &x; // here & means address-of because '&x' is an expression
```

Answer (score 0):

> **void fun(&x);**

in this line **&x** is "not reference variable", that is address of **x** variable.

Example:

`int y ;
int &z = y;` // `here &z is reference variable(a reference must initialized when it is created)`

Answer (score 0):

Here: `void fun(&x);`
You are passing the address (and not a reference) of variable x to `void fun(int* y)`.
Since `int* y` is a pointer, it then points to the address of x.